# Achecker Wcag 2.0 Prestashop

Tags: prestashop-1.7, wcag2.0

the https://achecker.achecks.ca/checker/index.php returns me an error that I cant fix it.

Success Criteria 4.1.1 Parsing (A)

Check 185: id attribute is not unique.

Repair: Modify the id attribute value so it is unique.

Error Line 1933, Column 3:

My site is on prestashop 1.7

Thank you

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO! I would recommend reading through [SO tour
page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and through SO help center on [how to
ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi. What  do you mean by "I cant fix it"? Is the issue in code generated by prestashop that you can't modify?